# Getting last segment of url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the code below to extract the last segment in a URL, but it doesn't seem to work on the URL shown below. Can someone please check the code below and tell me what I am missing here? Thanks

```
   var segment_str = window.location.pathname; 
   var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
   var last_segment = segment_array[segment_array.length - 1];
   alert(last_segment);
```

URL

```
   http://localhost/projects/myproject/app/#/sales/invoices/224
```

I need to extract only 224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `#` in that URL, so "224" is part of the `location`'s `hash`, not `pathname`.

```
var last_segment = window.location.hash.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

try `window.location.hash` to get the segment after the `#`, then split it.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Wu said, use `window.location.hash` to get what's after the hash:

```
var segment_str = window.location.hash; 
var last_part = segment_str.substr(segment_str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Will give you 224